# Why is Assembly printing a junk char from a return value if I print something first?

Tags: assembly, printing, x86-64

```
.text
.global main
main:    
    push %r13
    push %r14
    push %r15
    jmp label
x:
    pop %rbx
    movq $0, %rax
    movq $1, %r9
    pushq %r9
    popq %rsi
    movq %rsi, %r15
    .data
    a1:    .quad   0
    .text
    mov %r15,a1
    mov $format,%rdi
    movq $5, %r9
    pushq %r9
    popq %rsi
    movq %rsi, %r15
    call printf
    push a1
    popq %rsi
    movq %rsi, %rax
    push %rbx
    ret
label:
    mov $format,%rdi
    call x
    push %rax
    popq %rsi
    movq %rsi, %r15
    call printf
    mov $0,%rax
    pop %r15
    pop %r14
    pop %r13
    ret
.data
format:    .string "%lu\n"
```

The expected output is

5

1

but I get

5

The reason I say that it's the first print messing it up is that when I remove the print 5, 1 is correctly printed. I'm unsure why this would mess up the 1 when they are both printed using the same code.

Comment: What is all this complex assembly doing?

Comment: @fuz the main is calling a label which assigns the value 1 to a variable a1, prints 5, then returns the value of a1, which is printed by what called it. I understand that these prints could be accomplished more easily, but for my purposes, I need the code structured like this.

Comment: @Ped7g I use gdb. It didn't help with this problem.

Comment: try it again, verify the `rdi` contains pointer to format string ahead of printf call. It will not. Ie. you called the function with wrong arguments. If `gdb` doesn't help you with this, then I'm not sure what can, the `strace` may help with tracing system calls, but `printf` is probably internal part of your binary (even if loaded from shared lib?), so you need to either use debugger, or use your own logging mechanism to watch values in registers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem by moving the format string to %rdi after calling label x.